# Is there a list of possible stripe failure messages ($charge['failure_message']) somewhere?

Tags: php, stripe-payments

Stripe uses a token system where it is created client side and charged server side.

This question has nothing to do with the client side. The standard server side code is as follows:

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey("sk_test_xdxZgi0OEHrL1oG15p3ypN88");
$token = $_POST['stripeToken'];
$charge = \Stripe\Charge::create([
    'amount' => 999,
    'currency' => 'usd',
    'description' => 'Example charge',
    'source' => $token,
]);
```

This creates `$charge` which has a long list of attributes documented [here](https://stripe.com/docs/api#charges).

The particular attribute I'm interested in is [failure_message](https://stripe.com/docs/api#charge_object-failure_message) (`$charge['failure_message']`). I'd like to see the full list of possible values it could contain. However, without trying to generate as many different types of failures as possible in the testing environment, I cannot find access to *any* messages. I have searched the API references, performed text searches on the library files for "failure_message" (four results, none helpful), googled "stripe" "failure_message" but I cannot find a single example of a failure message.

This is important, because I would like to see if these messages meet an appropriate level of grammar and professionalism before deciding if I should pass them on to the customer directly or generate my own. Ideally, I'd like to read every possible message, but even reading a large number of them would be a nice compromise.

Can anyone find a list anywhere? (Even if it's not the complete list)

Answer (score 2):

My understanding is that there wouldn't be a list of the different of messages returned for `failure_message`. That said, in terms of error handling your code should rely on the information provided by the error object:
https://stripe.com/docs/api/php#errors

Particularly for card errors, you would need to look at the `decline_code` and if needed return your own messages/errors back to your users.
You can see a list of the possible decline codes here:
https://stripe.com/docs/declines/codes

Comment: Although not answering my question, I can tell you at least understood the question and gave a meaningful contribution to the subject. You got my up vote, but not the tick.